# Need help on figuring the best way to reset forgotten SVP on T410

Tags: bios, thinkpad, password-recovery, lenovo-laptop

So, I was replacing thermal paste on my T410 and disconnected the CMOS in error when disassembling. Now my T410 is locked with a SVP and won't let me in. I've tried all the password combinations I use but to no avail.

After scouring the internet, I have zeroed in on 2 ways  that seem feasible:

1- shorting the EEPROM - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANZjUPUYE7s

2- deciphering the password - https://sodoityourself.com/hacking-ibm-thinkpad-bios-password/

I find option 1 more convenient since it's faster and I do not have sound electronic knowledge. However, there are disclaimers warning that shorting at the wrong place might render the MB useless. From this image http://wallyoz.smugmug.com/photos/1150201931_6LQEq-L.jpg, I reckon that SDA and SCL are the 2 points where I need to connect my tweezers.

Can someone please confirm if this is the right spot and if I'm headed in the right direction? Or am I better off taking option 2?

Any help will be greaty appreciated

Comment: What exactly do you mean by SVP

Comment: SVP stands for Supervisor Password which is the BIOS password.

Comment: any ideas @qasdfdsaq

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone comes across this scenario with their T410, disassemble the machine using the manual and look at the back for the EEP ROM 
seen here [image: http://wallyoz.smugmug.com/photos/1193274544_r8Wuc-L.jpg]

Hold the pins marked with a tweezer as soon as the POST ends and the password prompt is about to appear.

You might have to try a few times to get the timing right. It took me 4 attempts to bypass the SVP. Once in BIOS settings, go to Security and disable all passwords and remember to save before exiting.